# Can we inherit singleton class?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

Can we inherit singleton class?

Comment: You will get the answer in the link below -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793507/extending-a-singleton-class

Comment: @Sachin Unfortunately the accepted answer that you linked to is incorrect.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It depends on implementation. Singletons usually have private constructor and possibly marked `sealed`, if it is so then you can't. If it is at least protected you can. If you just inherit from singleton class, result will not be singleton so you should follow the pattern and make it also singleton.

Comment: What if I create multiple derived classes, each inheriting from singleton class. I think constructor must be private  (can not be protected)for singleton class

Comment: @AtulSureka you can create whatever you like. The question is what do you want to achieve. Canonical singleton is supposed to have private constructor, but it doesn't mean that you must have private constructor. I can see a lot of possible useful variations of singleton with protected or even public constructor. Also keep in mind the fact that you can always call private constructor with reflection, so usability of the solution is what matters in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Keep base class constructor protected (and not private).

Then derived class can be instantiated but base class cannot be (even inside function definitions of derived class). I've tried this and it works well.

Comment: What if I create multiple derived classes, each inheriting from singleton class. Each derive class would create an instance of singleton class.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible way to handle a derived Singleton:

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> where T : Singleton<T>, new() {

    private static readonly T s_instance = new T();

    protected Singleton() {
        if (s_instance != null) {
            string s = string.Format(
                "An instance of {0} already exists at {0}.instance. " +
                "That's what \"Singleton\" means. You can't create another.",
                typeof(T));
            throw new System.Exception(s);
        }
    }

    public static T instance { get { return s_instance; } }
}

public class MyClass : Singleton<MyClass> {


}
```

Comment: Additionally, you may want to make MyClass sealed.

Comment: That doesn't work. MyClass would have to have a public constructor. Which means you can have as many instances of it as you want. So it won't be a singleton.

Comment: Jay, you are correct in the fact that you *can* create a new instance through the constructor. However, it will throw an exception if you try to do so. What I provided is a runtime solution and not a compile time solution, but that's the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot inherit from a singleton class, you might as well have implemented that class using only static methods, properties, fields and events.

Being able to access an object of a derived class through a static method (or property) of the base class is one of the key concepts of the Singleton pattern. To quote from *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software* (Gamma et. al.):

> #### Applicability
>
> Use the Singleton pattern when
>
> - there must be exactly one instance of a class, and it must be accessible to clients from a well-known access point.
> - when **the sole instance should be extensible by subclassing**, and clients should be able to **use an extended instance without modifying their code**.

(emphasis by me)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Why not? The inheriting class will be a specialization of the base Singleton class.

Instances of each of these classes (the base class and the specialized one) will be completely separate. In other words, their Instance members will point to separate objects.

Answer (score 0):

Only the singleton class itself can create an instance... so I supposse the answer is not. I think you can do it, but then it will not be a singleton any more :D